# multiple strings inside object array in javascript

Tags: javascript

so id like to add multiple answers to this array:

```
var questions = [

{
prompt: "What is the maori translation for: 
\"Apple\"\n(a).Aporo\n(b).Ako
\n(c).Whanaunga\n(d).Pene rākau",

answer: "a"
}
```

something like "answer: "a" || "aporo"
is that possible?
Any answer would be very much appreciated uwu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go down a different path.

Think of your question as containing multiple possible answers, and then save them as such.

Instead of 1 question with 1 answer, consider 1 question with several possible answers, any number marked correct. So I would build it up like this:

```
var questions = [
    {"question":"What is the maori translation for: \"Apple\"?", 
     "PossibleAnswers": 
      [{"text":"Aporo","correct":true},
        {"text":"Ako","correct":false},
        {"text":"Whanaunga","correct":false},
        {"text":"Pene rākau","correct":false}
      ]},
    {"question":"How many fingers on a hand?", 
     "PossibleAnswers": 
      [{"text":"3","correct":true},
        {"text":"5","correct":false},
        {"text":"10","correct":false},
        {"text":"4 and 1 thumb","correct":true}
      ]},
    {"question":"What is the maori translation for the french word: \"Pomme\"", 
     "PossibleAnswers": 
      [{"text":"Ako","correct":false},
        {"text":"Whanaunga","correct":false},
        {"text":"Aporo","correct":true},
        {"text":"Pene rākau","correct":false}
      ]}
]
```

By doing it this way, you can both have multiple correct answers, and greater control of how you present your question to the respondent.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var questions = [
    {"question":"Some question text1", "answers": ["answer 1", "answer 2"]},
    {"question":"Some question text2", "answers": ["answer 3", "answer 4"]},
    {"question":"Some question text3", "answers": ["answer 5", "answer 6"]}
]
```